# Mac freezes at startup at apple logo after permission changes

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I executed

```
chmod go-rwx /
```

Command on my Macbook pro yosemite. Since then its not able to boot up. It just sticks at apple logo.

Things I have tried:

- Mac repair  > Disk Utility > Repair file permissions. Completed Ok.
- Mac repair > Disk Utility >  Repair Disk. Completed Ok.
- Pressed (Cmnd+S) during boot > fsck -fy . The volume appears to be Ok.
- Pressed (Cmnd+S) during boot > verified permissions of all folders inside the / with another mac book of same specs. All were same.

Am I only left with re-install ?

Ps: I got that command from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6419695

Comment: Why did you run that on the *root* directory? That was talking about setting permissions for an apache folder. You're likely borked.

Comment: I am betting you had to issue the command `sudo chmod....` because only the root user can issue that command to that directory.  This should have been a flag that you are doing something "dangerous."

Comment: I thought  'For each parent directory leading to your web root' included everything, including /

Comment: "For each parent directory leading to..."  Not every directory leads to your web directory now, does it?

Comment: @AtulVaibhav when copying shell commands from the interwebs, *copy them exactly*. Don't modify them unless you know what you're doing. Typing `sudo rm -rf /` for example will *delete your entire system*. As Allan suggested, use `sudo`-requiring commands with care.

Comment: My project root directory is `/Library/WebServer/Documents/avp` so I thought `/` , `/Library`,  `/Library/WebServer` , `/Library/WebServer/Documents` and `/Library/WebServer/Documents/avp` were all to be edited.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't change ownership (users/groups) but instead only changed the permissions...

Try issuing the command:

`chmod 1775 /`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it:

1. Boot into **Single User mode**. ( Press Cmnd+S during start up )
2. Ran `fsck -fy` successfully.
3. Mounted `/` in read-write mode using `mount -uw /` so that I can edit permissions on it.
4. Executed `chmod go+x /`
5. Continued system boot by typing `exit`, voila! it all worked.